# Set array keys to value of another arrays values

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array of integers:

```
$iOrder = [3, 2, 12, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10, 5, 4];
```

I want to use those values as the keys in this array:

```
$pOrder = [7, 2, 10, 3, 5, 6, 11, 9, 4, 8];
```

I've tried this:

```
foreach ($iOrder as $i)
{
    $pOrder[$i] = $pOrder[$p];
    
    $p++;
}
```

I get this:

```
[12 => 2, 10 => 6, 5 => 5, 4 => 7]
```

I expect the `$pOrder` array to be:

```
[3 => 7, 2 => 2, 12 => 10, 6 => 3, 8 => 5, 7 => 6, 9 => 11, 10 => 9, 5 => 4, 4 => 8]
```

The length of $pOrder should be 10, not 4.

Comment: PS. The first array listed is $idOrder and the second is $pOrder.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php ?

Comment: And what do you want to have as result?

Comment: I expect the $pOrder array to be: [3] => 7 [2] => 2 [12] => 10 and so on and so forth.  The length of $pOrder should be 10, not 4.

Answer (score 13):

Do you mean

```
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

?

[`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array-combine)

Comment: Tried that.  Seems to be erroring using the above arrays as key/value.

Comment: Don't see any error. Additional, I don't know, what it should mean, when there only _seems_ to be something erroneous.

Comment: Fat fingered it.  Sorry.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Frist array, **$arr1**,
( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 [2] => 12 [3] => 6 [4] => 8 [5] => 7 [6] => 9 [7] => 10 [8] => 5 [9] => 4 )

Second array, $**arr2**,
( [0] => 7 [1] => 2 [2] => 10 [3] => 3 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 11 [7] => 9 [8] => 4 [9] => 8 )

If I understood correct, you want to use the values of $arr1 as keys in $arr2.

```
$values = array_values($arr1);
```

=> This gives you the values of $arr1.
you can use, `array_combine($keys, $values);`

so the resulting array would be,

```
$result_arr = array_combine(array_values($arr1), array_values($arr2));
```

However, it may not work as expected if the no of items in two arrays are different.